# No. of Comparisons to find maximum in $n$ Numbers

Tags: trees

Given $n$ numbers, we want to find the maximum. In order to find the maximum in a minimal amount of comparisons, we define a binary tree s.t. we compare $n'_1=\max(n_1,n_2)$, $n'_2=\max(n_3,n_4)$; $n''_1=\max(n'_1,n'_2)$ and so on.

**How many maximum comparisons are needed to find the maximum of those $n$ numbers?**

When drawing and trying out on paper, I came up with $n-1$ comparisons, but I'm not able to prove this. Any ideas? It's more or less easy to see if $n$ is divsible by 2.

Comment: nlogn for comparison based procedure. Essentially, this problem reduces to sorting which can be shown to be $\Omega (nlogn)$ for any comparison based procedure. But, if the numbers are fixed integers in a specific range, with counting sort/radix sort, we can get the complexity down to O(n).

Comment: But you don't need to sort the numbers to find the maximum. n-1 comparisons suffice.

Comment: Good catch, thought OP wanted the first so many maxima

Comment: This question might be more suitable for cs.stackexchange.com, here is a similar question: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35321/how-many-comparisons-do-we-need-to-find-min-and-max-of-n-numbers. Or perhaps programmers.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: The thing why I posted it to mathematics is because I would like to have an idea of a proof..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fairly straight-forward to prove with [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) that $k-1$ comparisons are enough to find the maximum of $n_1,\dotsc,n_k$.

- Clearly we need no comparisons to find the maximum of $n_1$.
- Consider now the numbers $n_1,\dotsc,n_k$ and assume that we can find the maximum of $k-1$ numbers with $k-2$ comparisons. Then we need only one last comparison because $\max(n_1,\dotsc,n_k) = \max(\max(n_1,\dotsc,n_{k-1}),n_k)$.

On the other hand, this is the best case possible, too: suppose that $n_1$ is the maximum of $n_1,\dotsc,n_k$. To decide that it actually is the maximum you need to compare it with each of $n_2,\dotsc,n_k$, i.e. you need $n-1$ comparisons.